# Apache mod_rewrite doesn't match URL containing percent symbol

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

If the rule:

```
RewriteRule myurl /newurl
```

Matches:

```
http://localhost:8080/test/xxxmyurlyyy
```

Why doesn't it match this?

```
http://localhost:8080/test/xxxmyurly%EDyy
```

**EDIT:**

I've just discovered utf-8 encoded works just fine. If I rather use `%C3%AD` than `%ED` it's ok. I still need to enable unicode.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to match just fine.  Given this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteLog /tmp/rewrite.log
RewriteLogLevel 5
RewriteRule myurl /stackexchange/foo.html
```

If I fetch this:

```
curl http://localhost/test/xxmyurly%EDyy
```

I see this in /tmp/rewrite.log:

```
(3) applying pattern 'myurl' to uri '/test/xxxmyurly?yy'
(2) rewrite '/test/xxxmyurly?yy' -> '/serverfault/foo.html'
```

And I get exactly what I expect (a document with the content "this is a test").

I suspect your problem is other than you think it is.  Enable RewriteLog and
see what shows up, and then post your results here.  Also, seeing more of
(ideally, all of) your configuration would help, too.

Comment: Hi larsks. There is no log output when the url doesn't match. May be it's a bug. I'm using Apache 2.2 for Windows 64 bit.

Comment: There's no output *at all*?  I would need to see your complete configuration to help out any further; even if the pattern wasn't matching you would still expect to see log output from `mod_rewrite`.  Does your `access_log` show the request, at least?

Comment: No output at all. Access_log is not working also. Here is my complete configuration: http://notepad.cc/flelsazbu54